# Код работает в windows но выдает ошибку в Linux

Tags: python-3.x

```
выдает ошибку IndexError: list index out of range
    count = 1
    i = int()
    pcount = 1
    for i in range(len(lst2)-1):
        if lst2[i] == lst2[i+1]:
            while lst2[i] == lst2[i+1]:
                 pcount+=1
                 i+=1
        else:
            if pcount > count :
                count = pcount
            pcount = 1
```

Comment: ничто в коде в вопросе не зависит от системы. Составьте минимальный но полный пример кода который проблему демонстрирует. Укажите версии Питона на Windows и Linux. Приведите полный traceback. [mcve]

Answer (score 2):

В этой части кода:

```
while lst2[i] == lst2[i+1]:
             pcount+=1
             i+=1
```

У вас нет проверки на то, что индекс `i` не выйдет за пределы массива `lst2`. Собственно, когда `i` примет индекс последнего элемента, `lst2[i+1]` не будет существовать

Answer (score 0):

Возможно в цикле while Вы выходите за границы, так как сам цикл идет до последнего элемента независимо от for.